# Scala spark multiple values in a column average them

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string, _2: string]` with column containing the value in below format.

***Input***

| _1 | _2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4 |
| 11 | 6,7,11,13 |
| 15 | 22 |
| 20 | 5,10,21,22,28,32 |

I want to find the `average` from column `_2` and also `count` the number of elements in it as shown below. What will be the most efficient way since this logic will be applied to millions of rows

***Output***

| _1 | _2 | Average_2 | Count_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4 | 2.5 | 4 |
| 11 | 6,7,11,13 | 9.25 | 4 |
| 15 | 22 | 22 | 1 |
| 20 | 5,10,21,22,28,32 | 19.66 | 6 |

Comment: Probably millions of rows is not enough for Spark and this simple operations. CPU can execute milliards operations per second (GHz), and Spark can just start in few (tens?) seconds. Depending on where are you data from and what you want to do with them later, you should consider to use just Scala without Spark. Just compare speed sometimes. Spark, as I know, good for distributed calculation and also allows to simplify/optimize some query operations, but it is not a silver bullet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string column then use array functions `size` + `aggregate`:

```scala
val df2 = df
  .withColumn("arr_2", split($"_2", ",").cast("array<Int>"))
  .withColumn("Count_2", size($"arr_2"))
  .withColumn(
    "Average_2",
    aggregate($"arr_2", lit(0), (s, x) => s + x, s => s / $"Count_2")
  ).drop("arr_2")
```